# QML FolderListModel filter out the files and display only folders

Tags: qt, qml

How to make FolderListModel component to filter the files and contain only directories. I want to display only directories in a list view.

Answer (score 1):

i faced the same issue, here is my workaround :

```
 nameFilter: ["//\\"];
 showDirs: true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the documentation I'd say it's not possible to filter out files from the list.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about this one, but you can try:

```
         nameFilters: [ "" ]
         showDirs: true
```